# material-ui, no such file or directory, open '.\node_modules\@babel\package.json'

Tags: material-ui

I recently added `@material-ui/core(v3.0.2)` into my project.
I need material ui because of material-ui-time-picker.
After that, my build doesn't work. 
Getting an error after `npm run build`:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '..\node_modules\@babel\package.json'

After I add empty `package.json` (to try if this will be the only problem) the following error occurred:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '..\node_modules\material-ui\package.json'

Is there any solution to fix this?

Version Details:

```
React 16.4.1
@material-ui/core: 3.0.2
material-ui-time-picker: 1.0.0
```

Comment: Probably just an issue with your _node_modules_ folder being corrupted. Did you try to remove it and `npm install` (or `yarn install`) everything again?

Comment: Post your package.json

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, I deleted the node modules and package.lock.json. Then, executed
**npm install -g npm**. That resolved my problem. And reinstall npm i.